# Working regex fails when using Scala pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala

In a following code the same pattern matches when Java API is used, but not when using Scala pattern matching.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

object Main extends App {
  val text = "/oAuth.html?state=abcde&code=hfjksdhfrufhjjfkdjfkds"

  val statePatternString = """\/.*\?.*state=([^&\?]*)"""
  val statePattern = statePatternString.r
  val statePatternJ = Pattern.compile(statePatternString)

  val sj = statePatternJ.matcher(text)
  val sjMatch = if (sj.find()) sj.group(1) else ""
  println(s"Java match $sjMatch")

  val ss = statePattern.unapplySeq(text)
  println(s"Scala unapplySeq $ss")
  val sm = statePattern.findFirstIn(text)
  println(s"Scala findFirstIn $sm")

  text match {
    case statePattern(s) =>
      println(s"Scala matching $s")
    case _ =>
      println("Scala not matching")
  }

}
```

The app output is:

> Java match abcde
>
> Scala unapplySeq None
>
> Scala findFirstIn Some(/oAuth.html?state=abcde)
>
> Scala not matching

When using the extractor syntax `val statePattern(se) = text` the error is `scala.MatchError`.

What is causing the Scala regex unapplySeq to fail?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to match?

Comment: It would be helpful if either the question and/or accepted answer could include "MatchError" somewhere in the content. The references to Java combined with no reference to the `scala.MatchError` exception generated when this happens makes it difficult to search out this entry when coming from a Scala only context. Here's the question I ended up generating as a result of failing to find this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66392638/501113

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define a Scala pattern, it is anchored by default (=requires a full string match), while your Java `sj.find()` is looking for a match anywhere inside the string. Add `.unanchored` for the Scala regex to also allow partial matches:

```
val statePattern = statePatternString.r.unanchored
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Z6XJik)

Some [`UnanchoredRegex` reference](http://www3.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.3/index.html#scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex):

> `def unanchored: UnanchoredRegex`
>
> Create a new Regex with the same pattern, but **no requirement that the *entire String* matches in extractor patterns**.
>
> Normally, matching on date behaves as though the pattern were enclosed in anchors, `^pattern$`.
>
> The unanchored Regex behaves as though those anchors were removed.
>
> Note that this method does not actually strip any matchers from the pattern.

**AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION** would mean adding the **`.*`** at the pattern end, but remember that a dot does not match a newline by default.  If a solution should be generic, the `(?s)` DOTALL modifier should be specified at the beginning of the pattern to make sure the whole string with potential newline sequences is matched.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. An alternative solution (which I prefer in my case) it to provide a .* at the end to match the rest of the string.

Comment: Yes, it is *almost* equivalent. If you use `.*`, do not forget to add `(?s)` DOTALL modifier at the pattern start, so that `.` could match a newline (in case the string has newline symbols). Then, it will be a generic solution. I added this note to the answer.

Comment: In my case I am matching against URL, therefore no newlines for me, but it is good to mention it for completeness.