# match a String based on regex pattern matching scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I wrote the following regex :

```
val reg = ".+([A-Z_].+).(\\d{4})_(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})\\.orc".r
```

which is supposed to parse  the following strings :
"S3//bucket//TS11_YREDED.2018_09_28_02.orc"
the parse method is :

```
val dataExtraction: String => Map[String, String] = {
  string: String => {
    string match {
      case reg(filename, year, month, day) =>
                 Map(FILE_NAME-> filename, YEAR -> year, MONTH -> month, DAY -> day)
      case _  => Map(FILE_NAME-> filename,YEAR -> "", MONTH -> "", DAY -> "")
    }
  }
}
val YEAR = "YEAR"
val MONTH = "MONTH"
val DAY = "DAY"
val FILE_NAME = "FILE_NAME"
```

but it doesn't work properly 
it is supposed to ommit the bucket name and parse filename and date

so the expected output shall rather be : Map(FILE_NAME-> TS11_YREDED, YEAR -> , MONTH -> 09, DAY -> 28)
Any idea how to fix it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+` pattern part matches the whole string first and `([A-Z_].+)` only captures what remains to be captured and matched by the subsequent patterns.

You may use

```
"""(?:.*/)?(.*)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_\d{2}\.orc""".r
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMmAPq/3)

Note that the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

**Details**

- `(?:.*/)?` -  any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible, up to the last `/` and including it
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars, other than linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\d{4})` - Capturing group 2: four digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d{2})` - Capturing group 3: two digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d{2})` - Capturing group 4: two digits
- `_\d{2}\.orc` - `_`, 2 digits, `.` and `orc` at the end of the string.

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/XRJxNe):

```
val text = "S3//bucket//TS11_YREDED.2018_09_28_02.orc"
val reg = """(?:.*/)?(.*)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_\d{2}\.orc""".r

var YEAR = "YEAR"
var MONTH = "MONTH"
var DAY = "DAY"
var FILE_NAME = "FILE_NAME"

val dataExtraction: String => Map[String, String] = {
  string: String => {
    string match {
      case reg(filename, year, month, day) =>
                 Map(FILE_NAME-> filename, YEAR -> year, MONTH -> month, DAY -> day)
      case _  => Map(FILE_NAME-> FILE_NAME,YEAR -> YEAR, MONTH -> MONTH, DAY -> DAY)
    }
  }
}

println(dataExtraction(text))
// => Map(FILE_NAME -> TS11_YREDED, YEAR -> 2018, MONTH -> 09, DAY -> 28)
```

Since you are not using the last capturing group, it can be omitted from the pattern.

Comment: I'd use `"""^([A-Z0-9_]+)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.orc$""".r` so that it matches the entire input (rather than just a portion of it) and considers `FILE_NAME` fields consisting of uppercase, numeric and underscore characters. Also, if the last number is to be ignored, it shouldn't be grouped in the regex (use `"""^([A-Z0-9_]+)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_\d{2}\.orc$""".r` instead, and don't add the `s` argument to `reg` in the case statement.

Comment: @MikeAllen `val reg = """(.*?)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.orc""".r` matches the whole string, it cannot match any *portions* of text since it is used in a match block. [`.unanchored`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155207/scala-regex-match-fails-java-one-suceeds/36155299#36155299) would make it find partial matches.

Comment: Agreed, but there's no harm in being explicit in the regex definition. :-) BTW, `[A-Z_].+` is wrong for reasons other than those you gave: it doesn't include numeric characters (present in the example), and the period following the `]` ensures that only ONE character in the range is matched, followed by one or more other characters - which could be anything. The period should be removed. Also, the OP's original code has 5 regex groups, but only matches 4 of them in the case statement.

Comment: @MikeAllen Let OP ask what they need to clarify. I explained how to make it work.   The rest is details.

Comment: @Wiktor , I updated the question , youyr regex won't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
val file_name = "TS11_YREDED.2018_09_28_02.orc"
val reg = """(.*?)\.(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.orc""".r
var file_details = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
reg.findAllIn(file_name).matchData.foreach( m => file_details.appendAll(m.subgroups))
val names=Array("FILE_NAME","YEAR","MONTH","DAY","DUMMY")
for( (x,y) <- names.zip(file_details).toMap)
  println(x + "->" + y)

//DUMMY->02
//DAY->28
//FILE_NAME->TS11_YREDED
//MONTH->09
//YEAR->2018
```